# MySql Server 5.7, win 10, нет конфигурационных файлов my.ini/my.cnf

Tags: mysql

Друзья, сабж. Файлов нет. Необходимо увеличить innodb_buffer_pool_size. Как? что делать?

Answer (score -1):

Решение найдено! Файл нгаходится  по адресу "c:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini", нго папка ProgramData была скрытой. Может кому-то это поможет.